# How to get addNA and xtable to work together?

Tags: r, xtable

I'm using `xtabs` to tabulate some data that contains `NA`s. In order to make sure the totals are complete, I'm using `addNA` to count the ones with missing factor levels.

However, this causes problems when using `xtable` to export to LaTeX for Sweaving because there are `NA`s in the row and column names now. I have a solution:

```
rownames(tab)[is.na(rownames(tab))]<-"NA"
colnames(tab)[is.na(colnames(tab))]<-"NA"
```

But this can become tiresome for lots of tables, is there a way of doing this more automatically? Or is there a better way of producing the tables in the first place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting question.  I couldn't find a way of dealing with this using xtable itself, either.  So the best I can suggest is to turn your workaround into a little function that can then be called easily.

For example:

```
# Construct some data
df <- data.frame(
  x1 = addNA(sample(c(NA, LETTERS[1:4]), 100, replace = TRUE)),
  x2 = addNA(sample(c(NA, letters[24:26]), 100, replace = TRUE))
)

# Create a function to rename NA row and column names in a data.frame
rename_NA <- function(x){
  rownames(x)[is.na(rownames(x))] <- "NA"
  colnames(x)[is.na(colnames(x))] <- "NA"
  x
}

tab <- rename_NA(xtabs(~x1+x2, data=df))
xtable(tab)
```

This creates valid latex without error:

```
% latex table generated in R 2.13.0 by xtable 1.5-6 package
% Wed Apr 27 17:20:21 2011
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
  \hline
 & x & y & z & NA \\ 
  \hline
A & 4.00 & 7.00 & 10.00 & 4.00 \\ 
  B & 6.00 & 5.00 & 4.00 & 2.00 \\ 
  C & 8.00 & 4.00 & 4.00 & 2.00 \\ 
  D & 8.00 & 5.00 & 1.00 & 6.00 \\ 
  NA & 5.00 & 2.00 & 7.00 & 6.00 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've decided "go in early" and use a modified `addNA` function, which I'll post below. Accepting your answer though as it still solves the problem nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution to consider is to use a modified `addNA` to allow it to output the factor level as a string in the first place:

```
addNA2 <- function (x, ifany = FALSE, as.string = TRUE)
{
    if (!is.factor(x)) 
        x <- factor(x)
    if (ifany & !any(is.na(x))) 
        return(x)
    ll <- levels(x)
    if (!any(is.na(ll))) 
        ll <- c(ll, NA)
    x <- factor(x, levels = ll, exclude = NULL)
    if(as.string) levels(x)[is.na(levels(x))] <- "NA"
    x
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice one, James.  If you _really_ feel strongly about this, you can go one step further and overwrite the behaviour of addNA itself.

Comment: @Andrie Not brave enough to overwrite the base functions just in case it messes with anything. Would probably need to change the default of `as.string` to `FALSE` to maintain compatibility.